Characterisation of smooth manifolds in Hubbard's Vector Calculus
I have a question about the proof of Theorem 3.1.10 on smooth manifolds in Hubbard's Vector Calculus. In part 2 of the theorem, it is stated that
If $M$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional (sub-)manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then every point $\mathbf{z}_0\in M$ has a neighbourhood $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that there exists a $C^1$ mapping (the partial derivatives are all continuous) $\mathbf{F}:U\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ with $[\mathbf{DF}(\mathbf{z})]$ onto for every $\mathbf{z}\in U$ and $M\cap U=\{\mathbf{y}:\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}\}$.
*I suppose that the set referred to at the end of the theorem is $\{\mathbf{y}\in U:\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}\}$, since $U$ is the domain of $\mathbf{F}$ (this is also the interpretation used in the following sections, if I am reading them correctly). I also noted that saying '$M\cap U=\{\mathbf{y}:\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}\}$' is different from saying '$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}$ for all $\mathbf{y}\in M\cap U$', since the former asserts that "only points on $M$ in $U$ are mapped to zero, whereas others points in $U$ are not".
The way this is proven in the book: (definitions are attached below)
Since $M$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then locally (in any neighbourhood of a fixed point $\mathbf{c}\in M$) it is the graph of a $C^1$ mapping $\mathbf{f}$ expressing $n-k$ variables $z_{j_1},\dots, z_{j_{n-k}}$ in terms of $k$ variables $z_{i_1},\dots,z_{i_k}$. Set $\mathbf{x}=(z_{i_1},\dots,z_{i_k})$ and $\mathbf{y}=(z_{j_1},\dots, z_{j_{n-k}})$. The manifold is then the locus of the equation $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$. The derivative is onto $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ because it has $n-k$ pivotal columns.
Doubts I have:

Denote $D_{U}=\{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^k:(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\in U\}$ and $D_{M}=\{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^k:(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\in M\}$  (where $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$; also I assumed WLOG that $\mathbf{x}$ is the first $k$ variables). If I am not mistaken, the domain of $\mathbf{f}$ should be $D_M$, which is not necessarily $D_U$. In that case, the domain of the function $\mathbf{F}$ used in the proof is also not necessarily $U$.
Even if the domain of $\mathbf{F}$ can be extended to the entire neighbourhood $U$, the proof above does not (at least immediately) show that there are no other points in $\mathbf{x}\in U\setminus M$ for which $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$.

May I know how to go about resolving these, or am I missing something? Thankss!! :D
For reference, a subset $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a smooth (sub-)manifold of dimension $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff locally it is the graph of a $C^1$ mapping expressing $n-k$ variables in terms of the other $k$ variables. The graph of a function $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ is the set of points $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{y}$.

The Hubbard's proof is based on the optimal selection of the neighborhood $U$.
My attempt:
Let’s take a point $\mathbf{z}_0 \in M$. If this is a $k$-dimensional smooth manifold, then there is a near $U_1$ where the intersection between $M$ and $U_1$ can be represented as the graph for a $C^1$ function $\mathbf{f}:V \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. Crucially, we opt for a smaller neighborhood $U = W \times Z \subset U_1$, with $W \subset V$, in such a way that $M \cap U$ is nothing but the set of the graph of $\mathbf{f}$ which is limited to $W$.
Introduce a mapping $\mathbf{F}: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ characterized by $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$. If $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in M \cap U$, thus $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$, which implies that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{0}$. On the flip side, if $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in U$ and $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{0}$, then it follows that $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$. As $\mathbf{x}$ lies in $W$, the point $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ is on the graph of $\mathbf{f}$ over $W$, which equals $M \cap U$. Therefore, we have that the set $M \cap U$ equals the preimage of the set $\mathbf{0}$ of the mapping $\mathbf{F}$ restricted to $U$ or, equivalently, $\big\{\mathbf{y} \in U : \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{0}\big\}$.
The derivative of the function $[\mathbf{DF}(\mathbf{z})]$ has the shape $[-D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) \mid I_{n-k}]$,
